# yAxis resizer to change svgrenderer position also highcharts

Tags: highcharts

```
I have a chart with some indicators below it. Each indicator area consists 
of a svg renderer button. so when I use resize property to drag and resize 
the panes, the series resized perfectly but the button remains in its same 
position, Can we move the button with the resizer?
Here I created a sample link to regenerate
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q0ybpnvx/2/
Any help will be appreciated. I am having great trouble. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add and position the custom button in `render` event:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        render: function() {
            var chart = this;

            if (chart.customBtn) {
                chart.customBtn.attr({
                    y: chart.yAxis[1].top,
                });

            } else {
                chart.customBtn = chart.renderer.button(
                    'sometext',
                    5,
                    chart.yAxis[1].top,
                    function() {
                        console.log('some task')
                    }).add()
            }
        }
    }
},
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b7vq4ecy/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. what if I save the button somewhere outside the chart object and try to update it in your way. here is the the button variable I declared https://jsfiddle.net/yq5epvmn/

Comment: Hi @Mitchelle, Yes, you can do that. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y2wbojqn/

Comment: `  data() {
    return {      
        btn:[],               
      
        stockOptions: {     
           
            chart: {
              events: {
              redraw: function () {
                console.log(btn)
              }
            },
                zoomType:'',
                spacingRight:30,
                height:window.innerHeight-51-56
            },} ` Can't access btn here

Comment: Yes, you can not do that. You need to put the variable in higher scope.

Comment: thanks again @ppotaczek. I'll try differently and let you know

Comment: [please check](https://jsfiddle.net/o2zf0sLd/) for two buttons, while resizing the 1st axis, the first button should move and while resizing the second axis the second button should  move. Can we do this?

Comment: Yes, it is very simple: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wn82qpuc/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do something by manually changing the x/y attributes of my svgRenderer label, the same should apply to buttons.

I'm in angular and have a listener for screen resizing:

Also Note that you can change the entire SVGRenderer label with the attr.text property.

```
this.chart = Highcharts.chart(.....);
// I used a helper method to create the label
this.chart.myLabel = this.labelCreationHelperMethod(this.chart, data);

this.windowEventService.resize$.subscribe(dimensions => {
  if(dimensions.x < 500) { //this would be your charts resize breakpoint
  // here I was using a specific chart series property to tell where to put my x coordinate,
  // you can traverse through the chart object to find a similar number, 
  // or just use a hardcoded number
   this.chart.myLabel.attr({ y: 15, x: this.chart.series[0].points[0].plotX + 20 }); 
  } else {
   this.chart.myLabel.attr({ y: 100, x: this.chart.series[0].points[0].plotX + 50 });
  }
}

//Returns the label object that we keep a reference to in the chart object.
labelCreationHelperMethod() {
     const y = screen.width > 500 ? 100 : 15; 
     const x = screen.width > 500 ? this.chart.series[0].points[0].plotX + 50 : 
        this.chart.series[0].points[0].plotX + 20


      // your label
      const label = `<div style="color: blue"...> My Label Stuff</div>`
      return chart.renderer.label(label, x, y, 'callout', offset + chart.plotLeft, chart.plotTop + 80, true)
  .attr({
    fill: '#e8e8e8',
    padding: 15,
    r: 5,
    zIndex: 6
  })
  .add();
 }
```